# spritzende Margarine? Was bedeutet das?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe auf einer Webseite diesen Satz gefunden:

> Für die Specksoße wird der Speck in kleine Würfel geschnitten und in einem Topf mit zerlassener heißer Butter (**nicht spritzende Margarine** geht ebenso) angebraten, bis er ...

http://www.tourismus-information.de/ostsee/rostock-warnemuende/restaurant-tipp/typische-gerichte-der-region-rostock/pellkartoffeln-mit-suess-saurer-speckstippe/

Ich koche fast nie, und deutsch ist nicht meine Muttersprache. Deshalb verstehe ich das nicht. Ich weiss nicht dass es mehr als ein Art von Margarine gibt. Können Sie mir helfen?

Comment: Eigentlich erklären wir hier keine Kochrezepte ;) aber: Es gibt Margarine, in der extra wenig Wasser drin is (das Wasser ist das, was beim Braten spritzt), die also besonders für's Braten geeignet ist.

Comment: Müsste es aber nicht `nicht spritzender Margarine` heißen, womöglich gar `nichtspritzender Margarine`?

Comment: @userunknown nein, denn in der Klammer steht ein ganzer Hauptsatz, in der die Margarine das Subjekt im Nominativ ist.

Comment: Margarine ist eine Öl-Wasser-Emulsion. Margarine beim Kochen und Backen statt Butter zu verwenden, ist eine Dummheit (die im Krieg aus der Not geboren wurde). Wenn man schon Pflanzenöl nehmen will, kann man auch gleich richtiges Pflanzenöl nehmen, ohne dass es mit Wasser verdünnt ist. Noch dazu kann man dann sicherstellen, dass es kein böses Palmöl ist (was ja meistens das ist, was in der Margarine drin ist).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Margarine ist eine napoleonische Dummheit in jedem Einsatzzweck. Aber auch Butter ist nicht pures Fett. Trotzdem müsste es doch wohl grammatikalisch und inhaltlich weniger verwirrend und damit richtiger heißen: "Margarine geht gar nicht."

Comment: @LangLancC Ich stimme in jeder Hinsicht zu. (Es tut aber der Margarinekritik keinen Abbruch, dass auch die Butter in handelsüblicher Konfektionierung ca. 18 Prozent Wasser enthält.)

Answer (score 11):

**Zuerst ein bisschen Physik:**
(Was ist »spritzende Margarine«?)

Margarine ist gehärtetes Fett, das aus Pflanzenölen mit Hilfe verschiedener Chemikalien (Hexan, Phosphorsäure, Natronlauge) hergestellt wird. Das fertige Produkt enthält bis zu 20% Wasser, was für das Hauptanwendungsgebiet als Brotaufstrich überhaupt kein Problem darstellt.

Wird Margarine mit einem hohen Wassergehalt aber erhitzt, so schmilzt natürlich zuerst das Fett, und es entsteht dabei eine flüssige Emulsion aus Öl und Wasser, die sich langsam in die Bestandteile auftrennt. Das schwerere Wasser sinkt zu Boden, und das leichtere Öl bedeckt das Wasser. Steigt die Temperatur dann über den Siedepunkt des Wassers, beginnt es zu sieden. Da kein direkter Kontakt zur Luft besteht, kann aber kein heißer Dampf von der Wasseroberfläche entweichen. Vielmehr bilden sich im Wasser Dampfblasen, die sich dann explosionsartig ausweiten, und bei dieser Explosion dann sowohl heißes flüssiges Wasser als auch heißes Öl in Form kleiner Tröpfchen mitreißen.

Mit anderen Worten: Margarine spritzt wenn man sie erhitzt. Je mehr Wasser sie enthält, desto stärker spritzt es aus der heißen Pfanne heraus. Nur besonders wasserarme Margarine spritzt nicht, und nur solche Margarine ist daher geeignet, gefahrlos über 100°C erhitzt zu werden.

---

**Aber jetzt: Deutsch**

**nicht spritzend** vs. **nichtspritzend**

Ich zeige es an einem anderen Wort:

> 1. Dieser Handschuh ist nicht leitend.
> 2. Dieser Handschuh ist nichtleitend.

Der Unterschied ist äußerst subtil:
In 1 wird ausgesagt, dass der Handschuh eine bestimmte Eigenschaft (*leitend sein*) nicht besitzt. In 2 wird aber ausgesagt, dass der Handschuh eine bestimmte andere Eigenschaft (*nichtleitend sein*) hat, wobei diese zweite Eigenschaft das genaue Gegenteil der ersten ist. Im Endeffekt wird also in beiden Sätzen genau dieselbe Information transportiert, nur eben einmal durch Anwesenheit einer Eigenschaft, und das andere Mal durch Abwesenheit der gegenteiligen Eigenschaft.

Daher bedeuten *»mit nicht spritzender Margarine«* und *»mit nichtspritzender Margarine«* letztendlich genau dasselbe.

Es gibt aber einen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen *nichtspritzend* und *nichtleitend:* Das Wort *»nichtspritzend«* ist im deutschen Wortschatz nicht etabliert. Folgende mit *nicht* oder *nichts* beginnende Partizipien sind einigermaßen gängig:

- nichtssagend
- nichtsahnend
- nichtleitend
- nichtrostend
- nichtanwesend
- nichtexistierend
- nichtarbeitend
- nichtfliegend
- nichtkodierend
- nichtkriegführend

Alle anderen nach demselben Muster gebauten Partizipien werden seltener als ca. einmal pro einer Milliarde gedruckter Wörter verwendet. Das bedeutet zwar nicht, dass ein Wort wie »nichtspritzend« falsch wäre, aber es bedeutet, dass es so gut wie niemand verwendet. Daher ist zu empfehlen, es ebenfalls lieber nicht zu verwenden. Aber wie schon angedeutet: Wirklich falsch ist dieses Wort nicht.

---

**spritzende** vs. **spritzender**

Vergleiche:

> 1. Der Speck wird mit zerlassener heißer Butter (nicht spritzende Margarine **geht ebenso**) angebraten.
> 2. Der Speck wird mit zerlassener heißer Butter (**oder** nicht spritzender Margarine) angebraten.

In 1 steht in den Klammern ein vollständiger deutscher Hauptsatz:

> Nicht spritzende Margarine geht ebenso.

Die ersten drei Wörter bilden gemeinsam eine Nominalgruppe, und diese Gruppe ist das Subjekt des Satzes. Und weil jedes Subjekt immer im Nominativ steht, muss auch diese Nominalgruppe im Nominativ stehen, daher muss auch das attributiv verwendete Partizip im Nominativ stehen.

In 2 stehen in der Klammer ein Listenverbinder (*»oder«*) und das letzte Element einer Liste, die insgesamt zwei Elemente enthält. Alle Elemente einer Liste werden gleich gebeugt, daher muss die Nominalgruppe *»nicht spritzender Margarine«* genau denselben Fall haben wie das erste Element (*»zerlassener heißer Butter«*), und das ist der Dativ, weil die Präposition *mit* den Dativ verlangt.

Comment: Auch normale Butter enthält Wasser; und spritzt. [Fett spritzt](https://www.gutekueche.at/fett-spritzt-beim-braten-artikel-2380). Das ursprüngliche Rezept ist daher irreführend. Das Wasser muss in allen Fällen erstmal raus. – Dies ist allerdings keine Kritik am Teil "Aber jetzt: Deutsch"

Comment: @LangLangC: Der Wassergehalt anderer Lebensmittel war in der Frage kein Thema und ist daher auch in meiner Antwort keines. Übrigens: Fett alleine spritzt nicht. Du kannst z.B. Rapsöl erhitzen, bis es zu rauchen beginnt und sich spontan selbst entzündet, ohne dass vorher auch nur ein Spritzer daraus entweicht. Erst wenn man feuchte Lebensmittel (z.B. Zwiebel, Fleisch) oder gar Wasser dazugibt wird's problematisch.

Comment: "nichtsahnend" (nicht sahnend, von Sahne), der Alptraum einer jeden Molkerei. :)

Answer (score 4):

Im Anschluss an Huberts fett- und sprachkundige Ausführungen (denen ich mich weitgehend anschließe) sei noch ergänzt - nämlich zur Erläuterung des Unterschieds zwischen *nichtspritzend* und *nicht spritzend*:

Wenn schon, dann sollte es hier doch eher heißen:

> Verwenden Sie *nichtspritzende* Margarine

denn die Zusammenschreibung macht es klar, dass es sich hier um eine bestimmte Art von Margarine handelt (nämlich nichtspritzende <sup>1</sup>). Das Wort *nichtspritzend* dient hier der Typenbestimmung.

Die Schreibung *nicht spritzende* ließe es dagegen offen, ob von einer *nichtspritzenden* Margarine (im Sinne einer Typenbestimmung) die Rede ist oder ob der Sprecher eine ergänzende Aussage zu Margarine allgemein triff ("Margarine spritzt übrigens nicht").

Möglicherweise finde ich mich hier im Konflikt mit Hubert, der ja zum Schluss kam, dass *nicht spritzend* und *nichtspritzend* das gleiche seien. Meine Überlegungen beruhen allerdings nicht auf der Betrachtung der isolierten  Begriffe sondern auf ihrer Funktion im Satzzusammenhang. Man betrachte den Originaltext:

> Für die Specksoße wird der Speck in kleine Würfel geschnitten und in einem Topf mit zerlassener heißer Butter (nicht spritzende Margarine geht ebenso) angebraten, bis er ...

Das kann man nämlich auch verstehen als:

> ... mit zerlassener Butter angebraten (Margarine geht auch, sie hat den Vorteil, dass sie nicht so spritzt)...

(Von möglichen kochfaktologischen Unstimmigkeiten in Verbindung mit dem annähernd gleichen Wassergehalt normaler Butter und Margarine sehen wir hier einmal ab.)

---

<sup>1) Vorausgesetzt es gibt so etwas überhaupt. Siehe dazu den Beitrag von LangLangC.</sup>

Comment: Keiner der beiden Sätze »Nicht spritzende Margarine geht auch« bzw. »Nichtspritzende Margarine geht auch« sagt etwas über die Existenz von spritzender Margarine aus. Beide Sätze lassen sowohl deine als auch meine Interpretation zu. Anderes Beispiel: »Nicht leitender Phosphor ist  weiß, rot oder violett.« - »Nichtleitender Phosphor ist weiß, rot oder violett.« Lässt einer der beiden Sätze den Schluss zu, dass es leitenden Phosphor gibt? Lässt einer der beiden Sätze den gegenteiligen Schluss zu?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Ich kann dir folgen (und sogar zustimmen). Aber du lässt den Kontext aus. Hier dein Beispiel mit Kontext: "Für Elektrokabel verwendet man meist das gut leitfähige Kupfer. Nicht leitender Phosphor wird dagegen naheliegenderweise nicht verwendet." Hier legt der Satzzusammenhang nahe, dass der Sprecher darauf hinweisen will, dass Phosphor im Gegensatz zu Kupfer den Strom nicht leitet, nicht etwa dass er über eine bestimme Art von Phosphor spricht (nichtleitenden nämlich im Gegensatz zu leitendem).

Answer (score 2):

"[Margarine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine)" ist ein *[Streichfett](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streichfett)*, kein Bratfett, gemäß EU Verordnung mit einem Wassergehalt von mindestens 10% und daher zum Braten [ganz und gar nicht ideal](https://www.stern.de/gesundheit/ernaehrung/bedingt-zum-braten-geeignet--verbraucherzentrale-warnt-vor-butter-mit-rapsoel-7628172.html). Wie auch bei Butter liegen Fett und Wasser ungefähr in einem Anteil von 80% zu 20% vor.

Da der Wassergehalt dieser Fette – [Butter](http://www.hausfrauenseite.de/kuechentipps/mit_butter_braten.html) wie [ebenso](https://www.gutekueche.at/fett-spritzt-beim-braten-artikel-2380) Margarine – die Spritzeigenschaften bestimmt ist "nicht spritzende Margarine" ein [Oxymoron](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron). Außer in den Versprechungen der Werbeabteilungen der Lebensmittelkonzerne gibt es eigentlich keine "nicht spritzende Margarine"! Allerdings hat der 
Fragesteller eine von dieser jahrzehntelangem Marketing beeinflusste Aussage ohne Basis in der Realität der Bratpfannen entdeckt.

"Nicht spritzende Margarine" wäre also gar keine Margarine sondern pflanzliches Bratfett.

Comment: Das ist eine interessante warenkundliche Ergänzung. Ich war bei der Lektüre der bisherigen Beiträge davon ausgegangen, dass es wohl irgendwo auf dem Markt ein Produkt geben wird, das die Industrie als *nichtspritzende Margarine* vermarktet und bei dem sie - wenn es mehr als eine Werbelüge ist - vielleicht das hineingerührte Wasser durch etwas anderes ersetzt, vielleicht Glycerin oder weiß der Deibel. Ich habe allerdings nicht recherchiert, ob es so etwas gibt. Der Verdacht, dass es das gar nicht gibt, sondern dass Bratfett aus Palmöl (bäh!) gemeint ist, liegt leider nahe.

Comment: Der Fragesteller hat weder gefragt, ob es nichtspritzende Margarine gibt, noch, ob man sie zum Braten verwenden sollte, noch wer den Begriff erfunden hat. Davon abgesehen beantwortet diese "Antwort" nicht nur die gestellte Frage nicht, sondern sie hat auch nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der FS schrieb: "Was bedeutet das?" Um zu verstehen, was gemeint ist, schien auch in einer anderen Antwort "ein wenig Physik" nützlich zu sein. Die nachgefragte Formulierung ist unsinniges Gewäsch in Klischeeform. Neben der Grammatik ist auch der Inhalt dem Vesrtändnis abträglich.  Dies versuche ich zu erklären und zu benennen, in offenbar notwendiger Ergänzung zu Hubert Schölnasts Antwort. Ich weise  daher diese Kritik als unzutreffend zurück.